# unable to get error response from servelt in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

i am trying to get error response from servlet in jquery ajax call while making an update in the DB .. now the update  function is running successfully and i get the `success response' . But when i make a mistake(intentionally) like adding a large value in field , it still gives a success message which means **only success message is running** although DB is not updated and i can see error in logs

javascript code:

```
            success:  
                   function(xhr) 
                    {
                       //if(xhr.responseText=="Row updated Successfully")
                          alert("Row has has been modified");
                    },
                  error:
                     function(xhr,status, error) 
                      {
                           alert("error");
                      }
```

servlet code:

```
    if(k==0)
          {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            pw.write("Internal server error");
          } 
         else if(k==1)
          {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            pw.write("Row updated Successfully");          
          }
```

k is the return value of the update function

Comment: You should also mention which javascript-library you are using since this is no pure javascript XHR. In pure javascript you would have xhr.onreadystatechange and inside that a check for this.status == 200 vs 500

Comment: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: And what happens in your servlet, when `k != 0 && k != 1`?